# Regularly used hotel apps have a strange overabundance of acknowledgements that have not been there before on iPad pro MRT

Tags: ios, ipad, notifications

My iPad pro is acting strange I noticed in the acknowledgement portion several with MRT ay the beginning in the Marriott and SPG apps.what is it and how do I get rid of it?
or should I iPad pro is acting a little odd I was looking through  I be concerned I know this is not something that has been there I know it's new and I mean there's just acknowledgement after acknowledgement with this MRT in the beginning

Comment: Let me know with an edit if I didn't actually answer your question. It seems you just need to disable all notifications or all notifications for those apps and you'll be set. Maybe there's something else with MRT you have that a screen shot of the message might help illustrate.

Comment: What do you mean by "acknowledgements" and "the acknowledgement portion"? Typically that's the title of an informational section buried deep in the app menus.

Answer (score 1):

When you install an app, it typically enables all notifications and banners or asks once and then enabled all of them.

I would go to the settings app on iOS (the settings app from Apple) and select notifications. I like to turn everything off - all the apps, none get a notification until I use the app and decide that I actually want to see notifications.

In your case, you can make a list of all the hotel and travel apps and then just tick them off one by one.